# Deploy multiple web services on a Windows Server 2019 with Windev/Webdev - IIS 10

Tags: iis, windev

I developed 2 web services with Windev/Webdev 27. They're supposed to be called on those URLs :

- api.mydomain.com
- feedback.mydomain.com

If I deploy only one web service on the server, without changing the bindings (*:80 by default) everything works well. But if I set api.mydomain.com:80, the deployement doesn't work anymore. If I add localhost:80 to the bindings, it works again. But I created a second web site in IIS 10 to deploy the second web service, and I can't set localhost:80 in the binding because it's already used by the first site. Here's the message that WinDev returns :

[image: Windev error message]

## **So my question is, how can I deploy/access different web services with different URLs with IIS ?**

Here are several screenshots of configurations you may need :

Deployement settings :

[image: Deployement settings in WinDev 27]

IIS web sites settings (sorry, screens are in french, but all you need to know is this is the bindings settings) :

[image: Bindings settings for feedback.mydomain.com]
[image: Bindings settings for api.mydomain.com]

Web Service Configurations enabled in WebDev Configuration :

[image: WebDev configuration]

Comment: Deleted all unrelated tags, as even an IIS/Windows professional won't be able to help unless he/she knows what is windev and how it works internally to manipulate IIS configuration. Please contact the tool vendor directly for guidance. It is not a well known tool, so you shouldn't expect many outsiders can answer such questions.

Comment: If it is an iis problem, then you need more information to analyze the problem. You can check if there are related error messages in the Event viewer. If it is a windev problem, I suggest you contact the relevant product personnel.